# Not able to add viewgroup using addview in composeview in xml

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Currently getting this error : UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot add views to ComposeView; only Compose content is supported

I want to add viewgroup to composeview.

```
mDashboardActivityBinding?.container?.addView(viewGroup)

\<androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1" /\>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. If you want to use a `View` inside compose, you need to wrap that view into `AndroidView`, which knows how to deal with recomposition over time.

You can check this codelab to see how it is done: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-migration#0